# Invalid character found in sheet title

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to load an Excel file from a certain source with PHPExcel. I have no control over how these Excel files are generated and they need to be opened automatically with PHPExcel without human interaction (re-saving the file, etc).

I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid character found in sheet title' in C:\path\to\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php on line 418

The error is occurring on the `load()` line, using the following code to open the file:

```
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
$excel = $reader->load($filename_xls);
```

The sheet title is irrelevant to us, so is it possible to just ignore it? Thus ignoring the error?

Comment: I don't really want to start messing with PHPExcel core files. And I'm guessing if I catch the exception *outside* of PHPExcel's core files, the file won't load anyway, which I need to happen.

Comment: You need to fix what ever is wrong in the title then.  If you catch the exception you can then try and fix the problem, then try and load it again.

Comment: You're right, of course. Just catching the exception will not really fix anything. Please ignore my comment.

Comment: What is the worksheet title?

Comment: print out the row causing this error so you can see what's wrong with it

Comment: For reference, the only characters that should throw this exception are `*` `:` `/` `\\` ``?` `[` or `]`, or if the first or last character of the sheet name is a `'`, or if the sheet name exceeds 31 characters

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm not even sure what it is originally. When I open it in Excel 2010, the sheet is named "Recovered_Sheet1", and there's a popup  saying "Renamed invalid sheet name.". I'm aware there's an "issue" with the file if even proper Excel warns about the sheet name... but I was more just wanting to know if PHPExcel can just lose the sheet name and continue like Excel can.

Comment: There's nothing built into PHPExcel at present to handle this, but I'll look at what it might be possible to do in the future

Comment: @MarkBaker The filename contains [] so I have a feeling it may be those in the sheet name too. So there's no way currently for me to open this file at all in PHPExcel?

Comment: Not without editing the PHPExcel code, no there isn't - the code in question is the `_checkSheetCodeName()` method in the `PHPExcel_Worksheet` class in `/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php`

Comment: @MarkBaker Ok, thanks for your help. I'll see if I can put something hacky in to get around it for now. Thanks for the great library though!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We've just done this to get it sorted for now. It's probably horribly bad and I wouldn't really advise other people doing it, but hey, it should work for us!

On version `1.7.8` of PHPExcel, in `/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php` around `line 414` - swap the `checkSheetTitle()` function for the following:

```
private static function _checkSheetTitle($pValue)
{
    // Some of the printable ASCII characters are invalid:  * : / \ ? [ ]
    if (str_replace(self::$_invalidCharacters, '', $pValue) !== $pValue) {
        //throw new Exception('Invalid character found in sheet title');

        //Hack to remove bad characters from sheet name instead of throwing an exception
        return str_replace(self::$_invalidCharacters, '', $pValue);
    }

    // Maximum 31 characters allowed for sheet title
    if (PHPExcel_Shared_String::CountCharacters($pValue) > 31) {
        throw new Exception('Maximum 31 characters allowed in sheet title.');
    }

    return $pValue;
}
```

Answer (score 25):

You don't really need to hack the core,  just add this in your own code:

```
// $invalidCharacters = array('*', ':', '/', '\\', '?', '[', ']');
$invalidCharacters = $worksheet->getInvalidCharacters();
$title = str_replace($invalidCharacters, '', $title);
```

`Worksheet.php` exposes `getInvalidCharacters()` public function you can use.   or get lazy and use the array() directly (copy&paste from Workbook.php definitions)

Comment: This should be the correct answer without hacking the core.

Answer (score 0):

You may passing special character at title. Please check the text before passing it it to title.

```
$sheet2->setTitle($sub_menu_title);
```